# new invoice gives: Total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract

Tags: magento, model, invoice

When i make a new invoice in the backend than 
Problem is: We then get: There has been an error processing your request ... Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

With a log ID number. Here is the full log:

```
a

:5:{i:0;s:74:"Total model should be extended from Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract.";i:1;s:2314:"#0 /home/../domains/.../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Total/Config/Base.php(70):Mage::throwException('Total model sho...')
/home/../domains/s../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Config/Ordered.php(83): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Config_Base->_initModelInstance('Softprodigy_Gif...', 'giftwrap', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#2 /home/../../../public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Total/Config/Base.php(88): Mage_Sales_Model_Config_Ordered->_initModels()
#3 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php(499): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Config_Base->getTotalModels()
#4 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Order.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice->collectTotals()
#5 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(86): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order->prepareInvoice(Array)
#6 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(177): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->_initInvoice()
#7 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->newAction()
#8 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#9 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /home/../../..public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#11 /home/../../..public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#12 /home/../../..public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#13 {main}";s:3:"url";s:91:"/index.php/beheer/sales_order_invoice/new/order_id/25/key/a66f58a07db7e62b5261a0846ca9b766/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the full log. Check var/log for the complete stack trace.

Anyway, "Softprodigy_Gif.." is a custom extension installed on your Magento and one of its "total models" should extend from the Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Total_Abstract.

Fast solution, disable that module and see if everything works. Further steps might be taken afterwards.